# React - ReduxJS auto log out feature

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, state

I am trying to make auto logout feature based on auth token expiring time. When certain time expires, It should automatically log out. I've tried with few solutions but could not come to resault (although I am on beggining hence I would have to store this in local storage as well).
Long story short, this is my code:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
console.log(!!initialToken);

const initialState = {
  token: initialToken,
  isLoggedIn: !!initialToken,
};

const durationTime = () => {};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logOut(state) {
      //   console.log(state);
      state.token = null;
      state.isLoggedIn = !!state.token;
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      console.log("keba");
    },
    logIn(state, action) {
      state.token = action.payload.token;
      state.isLoggedIn = !!state.token;
      localStorage.setItem("token", state.token);

      //action.payload.expiresIn
      //   console.log(authSlice);
      //   set
      //   const piva = async () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        authSlice.caseReducers.logOut(state, action);
      }, 3000);
      //   };
      //   console.log(authSlice.caseReducers.logOut.bind(state));
    },
  },
});

const authSliceActions = authSlice.actions;

export const authSliceReducer = authSlice.reducer;

export default authSliceActions;
```

As you can see, I have to call log out function and this work but the problem is that it doesn't change state and doesn't trigger component re-executing. (Redux DevTools confirms this).

Comment: You can't dispatch actions in reducer cases. If you always want to log out x seconds after logging in, put the setTimeout in a thunk or orchestrate this when your root component is mounted.

Comment: Well, redux thunk could work. I forgot about that option. I am gonna try it now. Thank you.